# Combining small queries into a larger mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

I have got an issue with getting 4 SQL requests to different tables within the same query. Queries are:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS posts FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type='updates' AND post_status='publish'
```

And

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS posts FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish'
```

The `wp_posts` table structure is:

```
|  ID  |  title  |  post_type  |  post_status  |
------------------------------------------------
|   1  |   Name  |   updates   |    publish    |
|   2  |  Name 2 |     post    |    publish    |
```

The other request:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS users FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%delegate%'
```

The `wp_usermeta` table structure is:

```
|  ID  | user_id |    meta_key     |         meta_value         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  29  |    4    | ei_capabilities | a:1:{s:13:"delegate";b:1;} |
```

And the last one:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value AS version FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='content_version' AND post_id=1
```

`wp_postmeta` table structure is:

```
|  ID  |  post_id  |  title  |    meta_key     |  meta_value  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  21  |     1     |  Name   | content_version |       1      |
```

Is there any way to combine them into one request?

Comment: one rwquest means ? As one query?

Comment: Hi @SubinCPoonamgode yes just under one SELECT

Comment: pls add the tables structure, or the field we can join between the two tables if exists

Comment: You can put the first 3 selects in a Select, but for the last one... Won't it give you more than one result ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona yes I need just a value from the last query. Do you think it is not possible?

Comment: @qqruza : Maybe it is, I don't know if there will always be only one version for one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two queries are similar so i made `wp_posts` as main table.The rest two queries as sub-queries.

```
  SELECT
    (SUM(CASE WHEN post_type='updates'  AND  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) as col1,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN post_type='post'  AND post_type='post' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) as col2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS users FROM wp_usermeta WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%delegate%') AS col3,
  (SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value AS version FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='content_version' AND post_id=1 LIMIT 1) as col4
  FROM
  wp_posts
  WHERE post_status='publish'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @SubinCPoonamgode. I have found a couple of errors in your example, fixed them and it seems working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   select(
    select 
    sum(case when post_type='updates' AND post_status='publish' then 1 else 0 end) from wp_posts) as '1Query',
    (select
sum(case when post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' then 1 else 0 end ) as '2Query'
    from wp_posts),
    (select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%delegate%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS users 
    FROM wp_usermeta) as Users,
    (
    SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value AS version FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='content_version' AND post_id=1)as Version
```

Comment: Hi @user3600910 I have got an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Another error - #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I have added the tables structures hope it makes sense